# Unable create Team's Channel with email address

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to create Channel of Team with email address (for example, General - Test Team 72 <527ce911.YYY.XX@emea.teams.ms>). I can create Channel but without email address.

I have tried following using Graph API (Powershell):
1. Graph API v1.0 and beta 
2. Create Team (public, private with email) with default (General) Channel
3. Create additional Channels for existing Team
4. Create O365 group and from group create Team
5. Add members and owners to Team
6. Update/change settings of Team and channel
7. Create Channel's folder in the document library of SharePoint site linked to Team

```
function create-team($TeamName, $Visibility, $UserId){
    $ApiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams"
    $Method = "Post"
    $MailNickname = $TeamName -replace '\s',''
    $Body = @{
        "template@odata.bind" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teamsTemplates('standard')";
        "displayName" = "$TeamName";
        "description" = "$TeamName";
        "owners@odata.bind" = @("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users('$UserId')");
        "Visibility" = "$Visibility";
        "mailNickname" = "$MailNickname"
    }
    $BodyJSON = ConvertTo-Json $Body
    $ContentType = "application/json"

    #$AccessToken is not shown here
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $AccessToken"} -Uri $ApiUrl -Method $Method -Body $BodyJSON -ContentType $ContentType
}

function create-channel($TeamId, $DisplayName, $Description){
    $ApiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/$TeamId/channels"
    $Method = "Post"
    $Body = @{
        "displayName" = "$DisplayName";
        "description" = "$Description";
        #"channelState" = "Active";
        "groupId" = "$TeamId"
    }
    $BodyJSON = ConvertTo-Json $Body
    $ContentType = "application/json"

#$AccessToken is not shown here
    return Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $AccessToken"} -Uri $ApiUrl -Method $Method -Body $BodyJSON -ContentType $ContentType

}
```

I can not create a Channel using Graph API (Powershell) of Microsoft Team with email address. I can create Team with default Channel (General) or/and add additional Channels but they all do not have email addresses. When I choose " ... -> Get email Address" of the Channel in the web page I get following message infinitely (couple days):

We're still setting up your team.
Please try again later.

In the document library (Documents) of the SharePoint linked site I do not see a folder General if we talking about General Channel. But after I click to attach a document to Channel in the Conversations tab I get following message:

We're setting up your files.
Check back in a few minutes.

and after several seconds arrise email address in the Channel and folder General in the SharePoint site.

Is it possible to create Channel using GraphAPI with email?

Comment: there are many different things written in explanation. Can you please be specific. Which email id are you trying to use as Channel Name? ( if you are trying to use any generic mail id then it is possible to use as name of the Channel)

Comment: It is not important for me what email will be assigned to Channel. When I create Channel using Web interface email is automatically generated and has format like General - Migration Test Team 92 <e1dc10f4.XXX.XX@emea.teams.ms> in my case (XXX.XX domain name). But I am talking about the fact that email is not assigned (not exists) after I have created the Team with default Channel (General) or when I add Channel after using Graph API (powershell in my case).

Comment: When you create Team using PowerShell, email address will be assigned when SharePoint site will be created. If you visit Teams>>Channel>>Files in newly created Teams after creation, email address will be assigned to channel. This is workaround but in your case this will not workout as you are creating Team from PowerShell. This is the limitation currently we have. Teams team working on notification api's, this should solve your problem. Api's should be out soon.